# write and wall commands in gnome-terminal 16.04

Tags: gnome

Recently I noticed that the `write` and `wall` commands don't work either in `GNOME Terminal` (after opening new terminal window) or in `Terminix` (after splitting terminal window). Neither the expected message nor any error appears.

These commands work only in `Terminator` after splitting terminal window. What is going on here? If anybody has Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME and these terminals, can you confirm this problem and/or suggest a solution?

Comment: Can you confirm that `mesg` outputs "is y" in your target terminal? It definitely works to send messages to a tty after enabling to receive messages there using `mesg y`. I can't get `write` to work on `gnome-terminal` (Ubuntu 16.04, Unity DE) though either. However, you could find out the pts file descriptor corresponding to the terminal you want to address (output of the `tty` command) and simply use `echo` to send your message: `echo "hi there" > /dev/pts/17` (replace 17 with the correct number.

Comment: Yes, I have `y` in output `mesg` command in all three terminals. This method with  `echo` works at me in all these terminals.

Comment: Same here, I'm as clueless as you now and also very interested in the solution to this problem.